# Can't install ruby due to missing packages

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, ruby

I am trying to install Ruby for the purposes of using Jekyl for static site generation.

I'm following the instaructions at https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/

and found an immediate issue:

> $ sudo apt-get install ruby-full

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  fonts-lato javascript-common libgmp-dev libgmpxx4ldbl libjs-jquery libruby2.7 rake ri ruby ruby-dev ruby-minitest ruby-net-telnet
  ruby-power-assert ruby-test-unit ruby-xmlrpc ruby2.7 ruby2.7-dev ruby2.7-doc rubygems-integration unzip zip
Suggested packages:
  apache2 | lighttpd | httpd gmp-doc libgmp10-doc libmpfr-dev bundler
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fonts-lato javascript-common libgmp-dev libgmpxx4ldbl libjs-jquery libruby2.7 rake ri ruby ruby-dev ruby-full ruby-minitest ruby-net-telnet
  ruby-power-assert ruby-test-unit ruby-xmlrpc ruby2.7 ruby2.7-dev ruby2.7-doc rubygems-integration unzip zip
0 upgraded, 22 newly installed, 0 to remove and 123 not upgraded.
Need to get 9907 kB of archives.
After this operation, 58.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 fonts-lato all 2.0-2 [2698 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 javascript-common all 11 [6066 B]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libgmpxx4ldbl amd64 2:6.2.0+dfsg-4 [9128 B]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libgmp-dev amd64 2:6.2.0+dfsg-4 [320 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libjs-jquery all 3.3.1~dfsg-3 [329 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 rubygems-integration all 1.16 [5092 B]
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 ruby2.7 amd64 2.7.0-5ubuntu1.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::23 80]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 ruby amd64 1:2.7+1 [5412 B]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 rake all 13.0.1-4 [61.6 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 ruby-minitest all 5.13.0-1 [40.9 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 ruby-net-telnet all 0.1.1-2 [12.6 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 ruby-power-assert all 1.1.7-1 [11.4 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 ruby-test-unit all 3.3.5-1 [73.2 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 ruby-xmlrpc all 0.3.0-2 [23.8 kB]
Err:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libruby2.7 amd64 2.7.0-5ubuntu1.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::23 80]
Err:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 ruby2.7-doc all 2.7.0-5ubuntu1.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::23 80]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 ri all 1:2.7+1 [4520 B]
Err:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 ruby2.7-dev amd64 2.7.0-5ubuntu1.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::23 80]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 ruby-dev amd64 1:2.7+1 [4632 B]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 ruby-full all 1:2.7+1 [2728 B]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 unzip amd64 6.0-25ubuntu1 [169 kB]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 zip amd64 3.0-11build1 [167 kB]
Fetched 3944 kB in 2s (1968 kB/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ruby2.7/ruby2.7_2.7.0-5ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::23 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ruby2.7/libruby2.7_2.7.0-5ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::23 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ruby2.7/ruby2.7-doc_2.7.0-5ubuntu1.1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::23 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ruby2.7/ruby2.7-dev_2.7.0-5ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::23 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I re-ran the command with the --fix-missing option, but this made no difference. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Did you remember to `sudo apt-get update` (or `sudo apt update`) first? it looks like the current version of `libruby2.7` is `2.7.0-5ubuntu1.2`

Comment: Nah I didnt, I forgot!! I'm a linux newbie!!! Let m try that

Comment: Hi @steeldriver, please post your answer so I can accept it. That worked, cheers

Comment: Done - please see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message

```
Err:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libruby2.7 amd64 2.7.0-5ubuntu1.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::23 80]
```

is because version `2.7.0-5ubuntu1.1` is no longer in the `focal-updates` repository on the remote sever - the updated version is

```
$ apt policy libruby2.7
libruby2.7:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.7.0-5ubuntu1.2
  Version table:
     2.7.0-5ubuntu1.2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2.7.0-5ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

The underlying problem is that your local repository catalog is out of date - it is recommended to always update it before attempting to install software from the repositories:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ruby-full
```